# Data-Bind doesn't work when using two separate divs with similar data-binds

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to make a FAQ using data-binds as there is a lot of information. I also have a "sticky" in the upper left as navigation. Both of these sections of code work when I comment the other one out. But the 'faqstickies' does not work when both are active lines of code. Does anyone know of what could be causing this? I am unsure as they both work on their own.

Here is the Navigation Sticky

```
<div>
    <div class="faqstickies list-group" data-bind="foreach: faqs">
        <div>
            <h3 data-bind="text: key" class="faqsticky"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the actual FAQ

```
<div id="faq">
    <div class="faqanswers" data-bind="foreach: faqs">
        <div>
            <h1 data-bind="attr: {id: 'faq' + $index()}, text: key"></h1>
            <div data-bind="foreach: value">
                <div class="acc">
                    <h3 data-bind="text: Question, click:showFaq"></h3>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="content-inner">
                            <p data-bind="text: Answer"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add js code ?

Comment: What would I be adding to the js code to allow it to show both? There shouldn't be anything in the js code that would be preventing it from showing both.

Comment: are they part of the same context? in that the $parent object is the same for both parts of the page?  you can add `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre> ` on your page to help debug the issue.  you can also do `ko.toJSON(ko.dataFor($0))` in the debug console.  the `$0` represents the currently selected element.

Comment: what do you mean does not work? is there any error?

Comment: They are both within the same <body> tag and both reference the exact same thing. The nav is just grabbing the titles of the sections which is called "key". The FAQ is grabbing the title as well as the question and answer. I would assume that this means it is both under the same $parent object

Comment: No one has been able to help out so far because you're not telling us enough... please show the js code as well as the error messages, if any.